# How do I completely remove Exchange 2003 from network?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013

I upgraded to Exchange 2007 around 6 years ago and thought I had completely removed Exchange 2003 from my infrastructure.

Now I'm trying to install Exchange 2013 and the install is saying that I still have a 2007 server.

Is there a recommended way on resolving this problem without having to find my Exchange 2003 installer/

Comment: Your question might have a typo...but maybe not.  Does the exch2k13 installer say you still have a 2007 server or a 2003 server??

Comment: Have you followed "Remove the last Legacy Exchange server" instructions? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg576862(v=exchg.141).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft have some good resources on this. [See here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg576862%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx)

IF you have already done this, then you may need to use [adsiedit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773354%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to clean up legacy attributes. Before attempting this, I would recommend you do some research on removing exchange 2003 via adsiedit, there are some good blogs around that cover this. [Example](http://blog.dargel.at/2012/02/23/remove-legacy-exchange-server-using-adsi/)

Comment: Thanks exactly what I was looking for just didn't know how to phrase it.